# How to truncate individual user data from database every time the user logs out.in rails application?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am developing a ruby on rails application and i am new to it.However i want a functionality wherein i want to delete all the data from the user which he has uploaded as soon as he logs out so that the next time he logs in again he can create different reports out of my system , without his previous records interfering the current result generation process. If someone can help , it would be great.I grab the user's data via its id.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to delete all the recorded added by the user and then want to add new records related to that. Right?

For Example:

You have a User table with relation to post table like bellow.

In user model:

has_many :posts

In Post model:

belongs_to :user

so first of all you need to get user object like this

user = User.find(user_id) rescue nil
Or 
user = User.where(:id=> user_id).first()

then check user is blank or not

if !user.blank?

user.posts.delete_all # it will remove all the user record
Post.create(..) # It will add new record in post table

end

Comment: yes but will it work automatically when the user will log out? Will all his records be deleted? I wish to implement that scenario

Comment: No it will not delete automatically, for that you need to implement upper thing s in logout method. so before log-out first delete all record and then log-out. is it ok ?

Comment: Yup it worked well thank you so much..appreciate it!